# Page title doesn't show in browser tab

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I am not a designer by working nature. And the issue I am facing is weird.

Here is the code snippet from MVC4 -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<link href="~/Content/Images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
@Styles.Render("~/Content/spr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>

<body>
<header>
    <div class="container-custom clearfix">
        <div class="col-lg-3 page-title">
            <h3>@Resources.Home.ProductName</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="container-custom clearfix">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/prHome")
</body>
</html>
```

Now when I see source code from browser, the title text is there. ***But the same doesn't show up in browser tab. Rather the url of website as localhost/xx/abc show up.***

Tested both in Firefox and Chrome. I tried cleaning cache and temporary files. But not helpful in any way.

*Can anyone guide me what could be the possible reason for same?*

Comment: Did you define the ViewBag.Title variable before? If yes, can you please send the website output source-code of the browser? If no, define it! :P

Comment: @ReeCube I had defined ViewBag.Title. I had pasted entire browser's displayed source code at [Title not showing](http://pastebin.com/NwqbdiYT)

Comment: This is really crazy, because when I save your source-code in a new html file and open this file, the title is showing up as he should...

Did you try to save the site to your local storage and open then the local copy? If not, please try this and tell me what it does

Comment: @ReeCube Now this is something really crazy. If I save it, the title doesn't save in file. But the title is there in source code displayed by browser.

Comment: Ok this is really really crazy, same result for firefox and chrome if you are saving the file?

Comment: So there's one more thin you can try: remove @ViewBag.Title by a normal string and check if the issue is solved or not

Comment: @ReeCube I tried with new version of Firefox. And still the issue persist. But when the page is saved from Firefox, the save file show the title.

But issue persist for Chrome even opening same file. Also the issue with simple text instead of ViewBag.

Comment: **A noticeable point -** When the page is about to open or the browser is showing as the page is opening, the title display there for seconds. But later get replaced by url.

Comment: Aha, noticeable point should help a lot, give me some time ;)

Comment: Can you please upload the content of the 'pr-home.js' file?

Comment: @ReeCube I found the culprit. It is the bootstrap file. Bootstrap v3.1.1 (http://getbootstrap.com)

If I remove this script reference (bootstrap.min.js), the issue gets solved out. I don't know what is there that is doing some mess with title.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49933/discussion-between-v-s-saini-and-reecube)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Big thanks goes to @ReeCube for analyzing different possibilities for issue.***

**True cause of issue -**

I was calling some function on some element on page load by jQuery. But that very function was not in existence. And so that error was messing with title part somehow.

**Solution -**

Ensure your scripts are not throwing any sort of error. I did it by opening ***Developer Console*** from Chrome by *Ctrl+Shift+I*.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue while developing MVC application which has Layout page & bootstrap used.

It was working fine for IE10+ but not for prior versions. There were no javascript errors found as suggested by @ReeCube & @VSSaini (checked through developer tool).

What I found was, though I had ***title*** & ***meta*** tags inside ***head*** section, the actual page rendered was containing these tags inside ***body*** tag, which was causing issue.

To solve this problem, we can put below piece of javascript code in layout script.

```
if (!document.title && typeof document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0] === 'object') {
    document.title = document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML;
}
```

That's it. It will solve problem for all the browsers

Answer (score -2):

I just tested and it worker with this code:

```
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/icon.png">
```

Comment: This isn't related to the title showing in the browser

Comment: I do agree with @Dean.

Comment: has nothing to do with the title problems of OP